# how do i assign a date to jquery ui datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to assign a date into a jquery ui datepicker. I have the date coming like 
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2011 . How can i assign this value so the datepicker.

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like regular JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object already accepts such format, so you can perfectly do this:

```
var myDate = new Date("Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2011");
```

Now, call [datepicker.setDate()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate) and you're done:

```
myDatePicker.datepicker("setDate", myDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker would set the date to the value in the box.

if the box is blank then the value will aways default to the value you mention.

There is a [CurrentText](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-currentText) Option but I dont know what that does.

Maybe [DefaultDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) would be the better option?

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
```

Comment: just had a re-read, looks like `defaultDate` is the option you want